# sendmail /etc/mail/access REJECT based off of keyword and TO: field

Tags: sendmail, spamassassin

someone  placed my email to a weird list and i get 100s of messages each day.

I want to block  the word "Unsubscribe"  in all body emails address to me@example.com

```
To:me@example.com  error:550 5.1.1 User unknown
```

Works perfectly  but i want to receive other email so i want to create some sort of condition

```
if sent to me@example.com
CONDITION Body contains "Unsubscribe" 
Then: error:550 5.1.1 User unknown
```

access.db gives me too many errosr to go that way  and spent too much time on it.

Any tips? spamassassin is intalled but i could not find any note on condition, sent to, and send reject 501 ref https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/branches/3.4/INSTALL

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Spamassassin is dead long ago, [rspamd](https://rspamd.com/) is the new black.
On one hand, adding the rspamd for just one rule will make your stack cumbersome, but on the other ... the thing you want to do with sendmail is perfectly doable... but sendmail lacks the templates for this particular case, so you need to write your own set of LHS/RHS rules. Which is way more difficult than just adding the rspamd into the stack. :) Anyway, if you'll accomplish this using sendmail only, you will be the only guy I've ever met capable of this. The other would probably be Eric Allman himself.

Comment: thanks tried rspamd it seems very complicated to even make a rule let alone getting it working.     thank you again .,